# Room onDelete with ForeignKey.CASCADE not deleting referenced row

Tags: android, foreign-keys, android-room, sql-delete

I have the typical one-to-one relationship between two tables

One entity/table has documents in it

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "documents",
    foreignKeys = [
        (ForeignKey(
            entity = Document::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["parentId"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )),
        (ForeignKey(
            entity = Attachment::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["attachmentId"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ))
    ],
    indices = [
        Index(value = ["parentId"], unique = true),
        Index(value = ["attachmentId"])
    ]
)
class Document(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long = 0,

    @Nullable
    val parentId: Long? = null,

    val title: String,
    val description: String? = "",

    @Nullable
    var attachmentId: Long? = null
)
```

and then I have this for attachments

```
@Entity(tableName = "attachments")
class Attachment(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long,

    val type: FileType = FileType.RAW,
    val title: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB)
    val data: ByteArray? = null
)

enum class FileType {
    RAW, PDF, IMAGE
}
```

My DAO for documents is this:

```
@Dao
interface DocumentDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM documents")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<Document>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
    suspend fun insert(doc: Document)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
    suspend fun insert(attachment: Attachment): Long

    @Transaction
    suspend fun insert(doc: Document, attachment: Attachment) {
        val id = insert(attachment)
        doc.attachmentId= id
        insert(doc)
    }

    @Update
    suspend fun update(vararg doc: Document?)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(vararg attachment: Attachment?)

    @Transaction
    suspend fun update(doc: Document, attachment: Attachment) {
        if (attachment.id == 0L) {
            val id = insert(attachment)
            doc.attachmentId= id
        } else {
            update(attachment)
        }
        update(doc)
    }

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(doc: Document)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(attachment: Attachment)
}
```

I can add documents with attachments, update them, add child documents (for which I use the `parentId` foreign key).

My problem is that attachments are not deleted when parent documents are deleted, even if I can clearly see in the table that the id of the attachment has been correctly added. Child documents, referenced by `parentId` are deleted in accordance to `onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE` rule but attachments are not.

The generated SQL that creates the table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `documents` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `parentId` INTEGER,  `title` TEXT NOT NULL, `description` TEXT, `attachmentId` INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(`parentId`) REFERENCES `documents`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE , FOREIGN KEY(`attachmentId`) REFERENCES `attachments`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE )
```

I really do not understand why one foreign key (`parentId`) works when deleting parent rows but the other one (`attachmentId`) does not

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have:

1. Table `Attachment`, one row with `id = 1`, second with `id = 2`
2. Table `Document`, row with `id = 1`, `attachmentId = 2`.

As I understood, you want after deleting row in `Document` table - row in `Attachment` table with `id = 2` to be deleted as well. But for that you have to change your db structure. Instead add foreign key `documentId` to `Attachment` table.

```
@Entity(tableName = "attachments",
foreignKeys = [
        (ForeignKey(
            entity = Document::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["documentId"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )]
)
class Attachment(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long,
    val documentId: Long, // <-- Foreign key to Document Entity
    val type: FileType = FileType.RAW,
    val title: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB)
    val data: ByteArray? = null
)
```

Since while deleting some row Sqlite looks all foreign keys in all other tables that are binded to that row and then deletes them.

**UPDATE: Addition below is misleading and shouldn't be taken into account**

And, in addition, are you sure your child rows really were deleted after deleting parent one? It seems you have to change `parentColums` and `childColumns`

```
ForeignKey(
            entity = Document::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"], // <-- should be childColumns instead?
            childColumns = ["parentId"], // <-- should be parentColumns instead?
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ))
```

Comment: Changing childColumns by parentColumns throws a `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)` when doing an insert

Comment: Also, I can confirm that deleting parent documents actually deletes child documents

Comment: Yeah, now I guess you're right and that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the foreign key for attachments and deleting them in a transaction

```
@Query("DELETE FROM attachments WHERE id = :attachmentId")
fun deleteAttachment(attachmentId: Long)

@Transaction
suspend fun deleteWithAttachment(doc: Document) {
    if (doc.attachmentId != null) {
        deleteAttachment(doc.attachmentId!!)
    }
    delete(doc)
}
```